# Hölder functions dense in space of bounded continuous functions (for non-compact manifolds)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $M$ be a non-compact manifold and denote by $C_b(M)$ the space of bounded continuous functions on $M$. Is it true that the space of Hölder functions is dense in $C_b(M)$ (in the $C^0$ norm: $||f||=\sup_{x\in M}|f(x)|$)?

Comment: Presumably you don't want just an arbitrary manifold, but a Riemannian manifold in order to have a canonical metric w.r.t. which "Hölder continuous" is sensibly defined.

Comment: What is Hölder continuity in the absence of a distance on $M$? Also: Hölder of every order, or of some arbitrary but fixed order?

Answer (score 3):

With $M = \mathbb{R}$, not even the uniformly continuous functions are dense in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$. As an example, take any bounded continuous functions with faster and faster oscillation, such as $x\mapsto \sin(x^2)$.

It's not hard to show that on any metric space---or more generally on any uniform space---the uniformly continuous functions are a $C^0$-closed subset of $C_b(M)$. So you can at most expect to be able to approximate these. I don't have access to the paper right now, but there is a version of the Stone-Weierstraß theorem [due to Isbell](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970045) that may give a useful sufficient criterion for when this actually happens.

Comment: About the Lipschitz approximation of uniformly continuous functions: there is a nice article on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity#Concave_moduli,_and_Lipschitz_approximation

Answer (score 1):

It is not: for instance on the non-compact manifold $M:=\mathbb{R}_+$ the bounded continuous function $x\mapsto \sin(1/x)$ has obviously uniform distance equal to $1$ from any uniformly continuous function.